# Why the difference in performance when using one index versus multiple indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing

Let's say we have a table named `impression` having three fields

```
id

site_id

timestamp
```

All the three fields are `INT`. We have to run the following query

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS c FROM impression
 WHERE timestamp<UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('09,07,2009','%d,%m,%Y'))
 AND site_id=11
```

**Findings**

If I define two separate indexes, one on `timestamp` and one on `site id` then I get results slower. On a certain data set this result takes `0.13 s` to calculate.

However if I define one composite index that includes both those fields in one  then the results are much faster `0.0002 s`

**Question**

Why do all indexed fields have to be under one index? If you have two separate indexes for them then why don't both of them get used

**Note**

Yes I could `EXPLAIN` the query but that's not the question, explain already suggests what I observed, but why does it have to be only one index per query

Comment: Mysql CAN use [index merges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html) since 5.0, however, a lot depends on the cardinality of your indexes, and it estimated the cost of the index merge (which is not the same as using a compound index) higher then scanning the results of using just 1 index. If you feel this is in error, you can try an `ANALYZE TABLE` first to update the cardinality, but the compound index seems a fine solution to me.

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks for your valuable contribution